# Separately solve and then later install Conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm working on a task that involves analysing the latest version of every package in bioconda. This can't be done using one large environment because solving the dependencies of such a large environment would take days, and may not even guarantee the latest version of each package. For this reason I'm trying to separately install each package in its own conda environment.

To speed this up I'm trying to parallelise as much of this as possible. Now I'm aware that [package installations can't be run concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58228286/2148718) in conda, because each process needs write permission to the package cache. However, it seems to me that creating and then *solving* the environments can be run concurrently, I just have to install the packages serially.

Now, I can run the solve in parallel by running `conda install my_package --json --dry-run > plan.json` in each process, which outputs a nice JSON file describing the solve for each environment. If I have the output from this, how can I tell conda "install packages using this already solved execution plan"? I'm envisaging something like `conda install --plan plan.json`, but such a flag doesn't exist.

How can I separate the solving and installation of conda environments? Or perhaps there's another way to install a large amount of conda environments in a different way?

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have also explained the broader problem: concurrently creating a large amount of conda environments and installing packages into them. If someone has a novel solution that bypasses my current solution they are free to provide one. If I didn't explain my current solution I would be neglecting step 2: "Describe what you’ve tried".

Comment: But why are you concurrently installing conda environments? Are the existing installations identical? How do you know?

Comment: Concurrency isn't core to the problem. The core problem is "making a lot of environments quickly". It's just that concurrency seems like a natural solution to this problem. But yes, I can make my question clearer.

Comment: Are these environments on different machines, or all on the same machine? I don't understand why this is necessary. If you're trying to reproduce an environment on many different machines, why not create a machine image, use docket or such like?

Comment: They're on the same machine. For each package I need to install the package at the latest version, analyse it, delete the environment, and then move on to the next package. They can't be installed in one big environment as explained above (believe me, I've tried).

Comment: I don't think there's a solution for your specific problem, but I agree with @PeterWood that there may be a solution for your root problem, which is still quite vague in the question. I think applying [Five whys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_whys) could help us giving better help. This is too vague: *I'm working on a task that involves analysing the latest version of every package in bioconda.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 4.6 at least, Conda has exposed a [beta API to the `Solver` class](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/api/api.html#module-conda.api). It turns out this lets you do exactly what I need. It is still in beta, so with the **disclaimer that this will probably break in future conda releases**, you can currently do this in Conda `4.8.x`:

```py
from conda.api import Solver

# Solve the environment, which can be done concurrently
solver = Solver(
    dir, # The location of the conda environment
    ["bioconda", "conda-forge"], # A list of conda channels to use
    specs_to_add=["bwa=0.7.17"], # A list of packages to install
)
transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction()

# This part must be done serially, so use a multiprocessing.Lock here
with lock:
    transaction.download_and_extract()
    transaction.execute()
```

Comment: Yeah, this is along the lines of what I would suggest, i.e., if you're going to programmatically solve for a bunch of things then better just use the Python package directly, even if it's using Conda internals.

Comment: Could you use the solver to include pip packages as well?