# Is it okay to run two instances of anaconda installing two things at once?

Tags: shell, linux-kernel, anaconda, package-managers, anaconda3

I just set up linux with WSL and am using anaconda to install standard packages.

It takes incredibly long (the solving environment variables part) and I want to install many things.

Can I run anaconda install on two different shells and be fine (using tmux not that it matters probably)?

Comment: I've never played with WSL but in general the package installation systems have a locking system that prevent parallel executions because they'll make the system inconsistent in some situations. So I think it should be fine but useless because the second process will be queued.

Comment: @DavideMadrisan Thank you

Comment: @DavideMadrisan if you post this an answer i can close the question

Comment: "*I want to install many things*" - the `conda install` and `conda create` commands both accept the specification of multiple packages at once. Also, if you want fast Conda environment solves, don't use Anaconda. Start over with [a MambaForge **base**](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge), avoid installing things in **base**, [use YAMLs to define environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually), and use [Mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba#readme) for environment management.

Comment: Do not do that. It may not be very stable, and conda is already having problem (sometime) with updates (and mixing with pip), with leftover files (and hard to debug bugs). Just take time to read some documentation (and maybe conda environment, so that you can have smaller environments, and so less time on dependency check [and how to clone environments: they break: you need to learn it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is conda install a thread-safe operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210335/is-conda-install-a-thread-safe-operation)

Comment: @merv yes, if you post that as an answer i can accept yours instead haha

Comment: You should accept the duplicate as proposed, closing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never played with WSL but in general the package installation systems have a locking system that prevent parallel executions because they'll make the system inconsistent in some situations. So I think it should be fine but useless because the second process will be queued.

Comment: This is not true for Conda, which does not implement a thread-safe locking system.

Comment: That's awful! So in this case is not "fine but useless" to run multiple installation commands but can broke the Linux subsystem.

Comment: Well, it's not going to break Linux, just might lead to some corruption in the Conda package cache. Conda doesn't install system-level software, so even if it breaks it's rather benign.